# Want to display logged in user details on drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I have a expo app,When I log in first thing that render is drawer navigator and I want to display the logged in user detail their but when I connected redux store with navigation file then I am able to get the user detail in my navigation file but that information isnot passed as prop to my navigation component.Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong

```
//Connecting redux store to my app
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('NAME' , state.auth.name)
    return {
       name : state.auth.name,
       emailId : state.auth.emailId
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(createAppContainer(MainStack));


//Displaying the data in the component
const CustomDrawerComponent = props => {

    console.log('DATA IN THE COMPONENT' , props.name)

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [name , setName] = useState('');
    const [emailId , setEmailId] = useState('')
.............MORE CODE


//OUTPUT 
NAME Jim
IN THE COMPONENT undefined
IN THE COMPONENT undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your MainStack connected to the redux store ?

You have to connect your CustomDrawerComponent to the store.

```
const CustomDrawerComponent = () => (...);

export default connect(state => ({
   name: state.auth.name
}))(CustomDrawerComponent)
```

Comment: Nothing changes...still not able to get the name and email of user...

Comment: Can you add a snack or a github repo to check your implementation please.

Comment: I need to see your drawer navigator too please

Comment: I don't see it :/

Comment: I need to see your `const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201329/discussion-between-prajwal-and-hicham-elabbassi).